# Firestore Export Cron Job Not Running: Error Code 204

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

## Expected

Defined Firebase Cloud Storage directory `gs://my-project-name.appspot.com/` to be populated with all of the collections in the `my-project-name`'s Firestore database when the deployed Cron job is ran on GCP with the implementation followed by the [Schedule data exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#configure_access_permissions) documentation.

## Observed

Cron job is deployed successfully, but fails to run. The logs are showing `Error code 204`.

[image: screen shot 2019-01-24 at 11 24 13 am]

**Logs**

```
2019-01-24 11:19:47.818 PST GET 500 0 B 998 ms AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) /cloud-firestore-export?outputUriPrefix=gs://[my-project-name].appspot.com/backups/ 0.1.0.1 - - [24/Jan/2019:11:19:47 -0800] "GET /cloud-firestore-export?outputUriPrefix=gs://[my-project-name].appspot.com/backups/ HTTP/1.1" 500 - - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "cloud-firestore-admin.[my-project-name].appspot.com" ms=998 cpu_ms=482 cpm_usd=0 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117c5fba456c9edcc5f075ccacb339b96d0bc7a8e35beb60cd3fd50a149d4c2f296b app_engine_release=1.9.71 trace_id=65811179272fc9c721d10e6cab7cdf70

{
    httpRequest: {
    status:  500   
}
insertId:  "5c4a0fd4000c78b4e510bd7a"  
labels: {
    clone_id:  "00c61b117c5fba456c9edcc5f075ccacb339b96d0bc7a8e35beb60cd3fd50a149d4c2f296b"   
}
logName:  "projects/[my-project-name]/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"  
operation: {
    first:  true   
    id:  "5c4a0fd300ff0c7e86eb62e71c0001737e636f696e76657273652d6d656469612d73746167696e670001323031393031323474313130333331000100"   
    last:  true   
    producer:  "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id"   
}
protoPayload: {
    @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"   
    appEngineRelease:  "1.9.71"   
    appId:  "s~[my-project-name]"   
    endTime:  "2019-01-24T19:19:48.816961Z"   
    finished:  true   
    first:  true   
    host:  "cloud-firestore-admin.[my-project-name].appspot.com"   
    httpVersion:  "HTTP/1.1"   
    instanceId:  "00c61b117c5fba456c9edcc5f075ccacb339b96d0bc7a8e35beb60cd3fd50a149d4c2f296b"   
    instanceIndex:  -1   
    ip:  "0.1.0.1"   
    latency:  "0.998139s"   
    line: [
        0: {
            logMessage:  "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."     
            severity:  "INFO"     
            time:  "2019-01-24T19:19:48.816504Z"     
        }
    1: {
        logMessage:  "A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)"      
        severity:  "ERROR"     
        time:  "2019-01-24T19:19:48.816507Z"     
    }
]
    megaCycles:  "482"   
    method:  "GET"   
    pendingTime:  "0.010711670s"   
    requestId:  "5c4a0fd300ff0c7e86eb62e71c0001737e636f696e76657273652d6d656469612d73746167696e670001323031393031323474313130333331000100"   
    resource:  "/cloud-firestore-export?outputUriPrefix=gs://[my-project-name].appspot.com/backups/"   
    startTime:  "2019-01-24T19:19:47.818822Z"   
    status:  500   
    taskName:  "6c799fe7c1a404ec22117967738fcca9"   
    taskQueueName:  "__cron"   
    traceId:  "65811179272fc9c721d10e6cab7cdf70"   
    traceSampled:  true   
    urlMapEntry:  "auto"   
    userAgent:  "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"   
    versionId:  "20190124t110331"   
    wasLoadingRequest:  true   
 }
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-01-24T19:19:48.824360342Z"  
     resource: {
         labels: {
             module_id:  "default"    
             project_id:  "my-project-name"    
             version_id:  "20190124t110331"    
             zone:  "us17"    
        }
        type:  "gae_app"   
    }
        severity:  "ERROR"  
        timestamp:  "2019-01-24T19:19:47.818822Z"  
        trace:  "projects/[my-project-name]/traces/65811179272fc9c721d10e6cab7cdf70"  
        traceSampled:  true  
    }

2019-01-24 11:19:48.816 PST
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
2019-01-24 11:19:48.816 PST
A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)
```

## Configuration

1. Billing is enabled for both the GCP and Firebase project.
2. A Firebase Storage bucket is currently created and in use to store *mp3* and *txt* files under a directory named *content* with a new empty directory named *backups* created to store the results of the export Cron job.

[image: screen shot 2019-01-24 at 10 20 20 am]

3. The following permissions have been enabled as recommended in the section *[Configure access permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#configure_access_permissions)*.

[image: screen shot 2019-01-24 at 10 17 02 am]

4. The GCP project is  defined as *default*.
   [image: screen shot 2019-01-24 at 12 05 35 pm]
5. The *[app.yaml](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#appyaml)*,  and *[app.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#appjs)* code has been copied as is.
6. For the *[package.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#packagejson)* the `name`, `version`, and `description` attributes have been changed specific to the project.
7. In the *[cron.yaml](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export#cronyaml)* the `description` and `url` attributes are customized. For `url` the following has been attempted in order to export all collections:

   - `/cloud-firestore-export?outputUriPrefix=gs://[my-project-name].appspot.com/backups`

## Attempted Solutions

1. **Version code:** Incrementing the version code on subsequent deploys.
2. **`cron.yaml` url:**

   - Adding `/` after directory: `/cloud-firestore-export?outputUriPrefix=gs://[my-project-name].appspot.com/backups/`
   - Adding `collections` query but leaving it empty: `/cloud-firestore-export?outputUriPrefix=gs://[my-project-name].appspot.com/backups&collections`
3. **IAM Permissions**: Adding *Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin* permission to my user account *my-name@domain.com* since that is the email account associated to the project under `gcloud config configurations list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the *package.json* version cannot be lower than `1.0.0`. I was attempting to use `0.16.0`. I'm sending a note to the documentation team as well as this should be included in the docs to save people time.